# Convertir clausula "In" sql a laravel 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Necesito poder pasar la siguiente consulta `Sql` que contiene la clausula "In" a `eloquent` en `laravel 5.6` y que no eh podido realizar.

```
SELECT sum(`monto_facturado`) FROM `peticiones` 
WHERE `id_presupuesto` IN ( 
SELECT id from `presupuestos` where `id_servicio` = 3 )
```

Comment: Pienso que puede usar  `whereIn` para solucionar su problema. Está trabajando con PHP?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez si el titulo dice Laravel es obvio que el lenguaje es PHP

Comment: @AlfredoPaz correcto mal por mi, de todos modos el puede solucionarlo usando `whereIn` , Aquí puede encontrar lo relacionado a las [clausulas where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: ¿qué has intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que todo, muchas gracias por su tiempo y por la respuesta, creo que logre resolverlo , usando el metodo "WhereIn" como me indicaron y dividiendo la consulta original en 3 partes, el cual dejo por si alguien mas necesita o tiene la misma duda. (Talves no sea la mejor manera, pero en esta caso me funciono)

Consulta SQL Original:

```
SELECT sum(`monto_facturado`) FROM `peticiones` WHERE `id_presupuesto` IN ( SELECT id from `presupuestos` where `id_servicio` = 3 );
```

Consulta Laravel:

1- definir el parametro de busqueda (En este caso el numero 3, el cual puede ser el request de un formulario o similar)

```
$idservicio = $request->id; // 3
```

2- generar la subconsulta que va después del "IN" , el cual me generara el listado de ids que contengan dicho valor buscado. (generera un array el cual sera valido para usar el WhereIn).

```
 $selpre = Presupuesto::where('id_servicio', '=', $idservicio)->pluck('id');
```

3- Teniendo el dato del punto 2 , ahora se puede generar la consulta usando el wherein.

```
$totalsuma = Peticiones::whereIn('id_presupuesto', $selpre)->sum('monto_facturado');
```

Cabe destacar que en esta caso fueron 3 tablas (peticiones, presupuestos y servicios), relacionadas con fks.

PD: si alguien sabe otra solucion mas simple o mas ordenada , igual se agradece.